# My iPhone 5s won't make any sound at all

Tags: iphone

My iPhone has recently stopped making any sound, it will only vibrate when something happens, and I can only hear anything when I'm calling someone or have headphones in.  I know that there isn't a blown out speaker, I've checked to see that it isn't on silent or on do not disturb, what do I do?

Comment: How do you know the loud speaker isn't faulty?

Comment: I don't, but how would I know, it's a refurbished phone, and I got it a couple weeks ago, sorry I'm terrible st technology

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the position of the mute switch on the upper left edge of the iPhone itself? If you see a red indication, this switch has been enabled:

[image]

Comment: I have checked that, and it's off